# Rails: Update to ancestry parent not persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I tried to change the parent of all siblings of an ancestry model (code from the activity model):

```
def change_parents_of_siblings
  to_change = self.siblings.where.not(id: self.id)
  to_change.each do |sib|
    sib.update!(parent: self)
  end
end
```

If I print all the ids inside the function (like sib.id, ...) to the console it seems to work. But after the function call none of these changes are persisted. For example:

```
@activity1 = Activity.create(name:"test1")
@activity2 = Activity.create(name:"test2", parent_id: @activity1.id )
@activity15 = Activity.create(name:"test1.5", parent_id: @activity1.id)
@activity15.change_parents_of_siblings

expect(@activity2.parent_id).to eq(@activity15.id)
```

fails.

Comment: What is `self.siblings`? You're trying to set parent on all `siblings` of an `Activity`, but expect `Activity`'s parent_id to change? And could you, please, tell more about relations. Which one has another, and which one belongs to another.

Comment: The question is related to the ancestry gem. Activity has_ancestry so this class has ancestry related attributes like parent and parent_id and also ancestry instance methods like root, children, siblings, ... . There is no AR:Association involved.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a bath I found the problem myself.

The change_parents_of_siblings method changed the ancestry in the database. BUt this is not recognized by Rails as a change on the model.

So I had to call `@activity2.reload` before using it again.

Sorry for taking your time.